# How to play some audio on shell bash script

Tags: bash, shell, audio

i wrote a simple script. on thats script i want play some audio that I can choose with format .mp3,

```
   findsounds=`find |*.mp3 | zenity --list --column "play it!"`
```

please told me, what is the next script i can write? hehe

Comment: And what is the question? (exactly).

Comment: that script doesn't work,
so, what should I do?

Comment: Sure. Welcome here. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: sounds=$(find | *.mp3 | zenity --list --column "choose sounds");